HTML Email padding not respected in SendGrid for Outlook
I'm sending email via SendGrid and trying to work with dynamic templates.  Outlook is maddening in this...
I have this code section in one of my templates:
<div class="contentSection"> 
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="purchaseQty" style="font-weight: bold">QTY</td>
            <td class="purchaseFill" style="font-weight: bold">ITEM</td>
            <td class="purchaseCurrency" style="font-weight: bold">COST (USD)</td>
        </tr>
        {{#each items}}
        <tr>
            <td class="purchaseQty">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 3px; font-weight: bold">{{this.quantity}}</div>
            </td>
            <td class="purchaseFill">
                <div style="margin-bottom: 3px; font-weight: bold">
                    {{this.itemName}}{{this.quantityUpdate}}{{this.licenseUpdate}}
                    {{#unless this.features}}
                    {{this.featureUpdate}}
                    {{/unless}}
                </div>
                <div>Expires: {{this.expiration}}{{this.expiryUpdate}}</div>
                {{#if this.features}}
                <div>Features: {{this.features}}{{this.featureUpdate}}</div>
                {{/if}}
                <div>Key: {{this.key}}</div>
                {{#if this.errorString}}
                <div class="errorDivWrapper">
                    <div class="errorDiv" style="padding: 10px">Warning! There were some errors processing this license, please contact Revolution Design for support.</div>
                </div>
                {{/if}}
            </td>
            <td class="purchaseCurrency">
                <div style="font-weight: bold">{{this.itemCost}}</div>
                {{#if this.discount}}
                <div style="color: red; font-size: 12px; font-style: italic">(-{{this.discount}})</div>
                {{/if}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

It uses these styles from the custom head:
.contentSection{
    margin: 0px 40px 10px 40px;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.purchaseQty{
    width: 10%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.purchaseFill{
    width: 60%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.purchaseCurrency{
    width: 30%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    align-content: baseline;
    text-align: right;
}

.errorDivWrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: wheat;
}

.errorDiv{
    padding: 20px;
}

As it's set up here, Outlook looks correct; this section has the 40 px between the right edge of the main section and the right side of the text.  However, when I send to yahoo or other mail there is 80px there.  Yahoo is actually correct here as there should be a 40px margin on the content section and a 40px padding in the cell.  I can take one of them out and make it so that it should be 40px, but then Outlook gives me 0px.
I have tried:

Making the outside piece a table instead of a div.
Directly setting the width of the table to 520px (600 less the 2 40px margins).
Setting and unsetting the table width.
Using padding instead of margin on the main div.
Setting the width of the table via the width property and the style property.

I feel like maybe 1 or 2 more things but I can't remember now.  Regardless of what I do Outlook will not recognize the same as Yahoo, it's wrong in either one or the other.
How the heck do you get this to appear correctly in both???

Ok, after much frustration I figured out something that works.  It doesn't like padding or margins in div's apparently. I ended up having to take the margin out of contentSection entirely.  I then put 40px of right and left padding in purchaseQty and purchaseCurrency.  That seems to recognize properly in both systems.
Now the remaining (rhetorical) question is why the heck hasn't Microsoft updated the HTML system in Outlook since like 1997...
